# Page curl by harism, text is shown not normal on two page mode

Tags: android, page-curl

I'm using page curl animation by Harism https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl‎. I'm testing this project by drawing text not image. When it is one page mode, it is showing normal text: [image]

However when it is two page mode (landscape) result is like below:
[image]

problem is text's state on left side. There is a method **onSizeChanged** which controls screen orientation and changes page mode:

```
 @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
            if (w > h) { 
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
               mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
            } else { 
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
                mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
    }
    }
```

After changing mode, page rects will be updated

> ```
> private void updatePageRects() {
>       if (mViewRect.width() == 0 || mViewRect.height() == 0) {
>           return;
>       } else if (mViewMode == SHOW_ONE_PAGE) {
>           mPageRectRight.set(mViewRect);
>           mPageRectRight.left += mViewRect.width() * mMargins.left;
>           mPageRectRight.right -= mViewRect.width() * mMargins.right;
>           mPageRectRight.top += mViewRect.height() * mMargins.top;
>           mPageRectRight.bottom -= mViewRect.height() * mMargins.bottom;
>
>           mPageRectLeft.set(mPageRectRight);
>           mPageRectLeft.offset(-mPageRectRight.width(), 0);
>
>           int bitmapW = (int) ((mPageRectRight.width() * mViewportWidth) / mViewRect
>                   .width());
>           int bitmapH = (int) ((mPageRectRight.height() * mViewportHeight) / mViewRect
>                   .height());
>           mObserver.onPageSizeChanged(bitmapW, bitmapH);
>       } else if (mViewMode == SHOW_TWO_PAGES) {
>           mPageRectRight.set(mViewRect);
>           mPageRectRight.left += mViewRect.width() * mMargins.left;
>           mPageRectRight.right -= mViewRect.width() * mMargins.right;
>           mPageRectRight.top += mViewRect.height() * mMargins.top;
>           mPageRectRight.bottom -= mViewRect.height() * mMargins.bottom;
>
>           mPageRectLeft.set(mPageRectRight);
>           mPageRectLeft.right = (mPageRectLeft.right + mPageRectLeft.left) / 2;
>           mPageRectRight.left = mPageRectLeft.right;
>
>           int bitmapW = (int) ((mPageRectRight.width() * mViewportWidth) / mViewRect
>                   .width());
>           int bitmapH = (int) ((mPageRectRight.height() * mViewportHeight) / mViewRect
>                   .height());
>           mObserver.onPageSizeChanged(bitmapW, bitmapH);
>       }
>   }
> ```

This project created using OpenGL/ES. Any help?

Comment: It seems that your texture coordinates for the left side are not correct. It might be another feature / bug of the curl library. Some code, indicating how you change to two-page mode would help.

Comment: @the swine I have updated my question

Comment: It seems quite reasonable. What happens if you swap `mPageRectLeft.right` for `mPageRectLeft.left` at the end of the `if(mViewMode == SHOW_TWO_PAGES)` block?

Comment: Well, actually, looking more into how curl works it seems that this is "correct" behavior, as the left page is set to be flipped and un-flipped at times. It seems that this library was written to confuse people.

Comment: And how can we solve this problem?

Comment: There are also front and back textures for every page. Are you supplying both textures?

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried all tricks: front, back and both textures, but result is not better

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48862/discussion-between-support-ms-and-the-swine)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like yet another bug in the library. The code, regarding two-page functionality was recently updated, according to the GitHub comments. I suggest contacting the author and requesting a fix.

Comment: I found another old version of this project here github.com/cags12/android_page_curl. Pages on left side are shown correct. Now, we should find what kind of changes were made, that affected left side images becoming at wrong position

Comment: Great, now you're getting somewhere.